# VS JavaScript intellisense with paramaters

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

here is some sample javascript:

```
SomeObjectType = function() {
}

SomeObjectType.prototype = {
    field1: null,
    field2: null
}

SomeOtherObject = function() {
}

SomeOtherObject.prototype =
{
    doSomething: function(val) {
        /// <param name="val" type="SomeObjectType"></param>
        var val2 = new SomeObjectType();
        //val2. shows intellisense correctly
        //val. does NOT


    }
}
```

Shouldn't visual studio be giving me intellisence when i do "val." inside the "doSomething" function?  I would expect it to give me field1 and field2 as options, but it doesn't.  I DO get field1 and field2 if I type "val2." so intellisence works when I create a new object of the same type that I specify in the param comment.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not supported in VS 2008. It will be supported in the next version.

In VS 2008, the XML comments are only used to generate tooltip information. And I think the tooltips may only be supported in referenced files.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported on VS2010. But why only for the prototype methods? :(